# How to change font family with spplot?

Tags: r

Please can you advise how to change font family with spplot? I've been looking in the ?spplot and have tried many things like:

```
trellis.par.set(fontfamily = "mono", family = "mono")
spplot(xxKv[,"value"], 
    main=list(label="Testfont Jilm JILM",cex=3),
    par.settings = list(fontfamily = "mono"),
    family = "mono",
    fontfamily = "mono",
    labels = list(fontfamily = "mono")
)
```

But with no effect.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, found by just a random experiment!

```
spplot(xxKv[,"value"], 
    main=list(label="Testfont Jilm JILM",cex=3,fontfamily="mono")
)
```